# ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server(-1)

Tags: ldap

This is my /etc/hosts file:

[image: This is my /etc/hosts file:]

This is my ldap.conf file:

[image: This is my ldap.conf file:]

I am getting

> "ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server(-1)"

when I run this command:

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://ldap.techvictus.local" -P 3 -LLL -b "dc=techvictus,dc=local"
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. It is better to paste the actual text of the files into the question, rather than use an image. You can add them using the [edit] button.

Comment: thanks, will remember it next time (rookie here :) )...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the hostname `ldap.techvictus.local` is actually addressable... (i.e. a hostname that can be resolved in an IP address).

Try `ldap://localhost`

Comment: yes, its working with ldap://localhost. Thanks, but that's only for the server right, what if we want to integrate this LDAP server with say OVD then how will that communication take place?

Comment: Well, you should indicate a hostname that is registered in DNS and can be contacted from the network.

Answer (score 3):

I had followed this link is working fine for me

**https://lea-linux.org/documentations/Trucs:Ldap_sasl_bind_cant_contact_LDAP_server**

The idea for above link just make sure the parameter in the **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf** has paramters are setting like this.

**TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/certs**

**TLS_REQCERT never**

Comment: I had this entries, But there was some alignment issue in the ldap.conf file. Once the alignment and the indenting are sorted after the restart of the LDAP services It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you've figured it out by now but leaving a comment here for others.

I was having the same issue and I realized that the domain name I was using was just a made-up (fake domain name like: `marvel.comics`). So I modified `ldap.conf` to have `URI  ldap://${IP_ADDRESS}` and it worked.

It seems like you originally configured your ldap.conf with your IP address. However, your `/etc/hosts` seems odd to me.

I recommend using your system's IP address rather than `127.0.1.1`. Also use FQDN after the IP address.

```
192.168.1.123 hulk.marvel.comics hulk
127.0.0.1 localhost

and the rest...
```